# How do I read a file line by line and print the line that have specific string only in python?

Tags: python

I have a text file containing these lines

```
wbwubddwo 7::a number1 234 **
/// 45daa;: number2 12

time 3:44
```

I am trying to print for example if the program find string `number1`, it will print `234`

I start with simple script below but it did not print what I wanted.

```
with open("test.txt", "rb") as f:
    lines = f.read()
    word = ["number1", "number2", "time"]
    if any(item in lines for item in word):
        val1 = lines.split("number1 ", 1)[1]
        print val1
```

This return the following result

```
234 **
/// 45daa;: number2 12

time 3:44
```

Then I tried changing `f.read()` to `f.readlines()` but this time it did not print out anything.

Does anyone know other way to do this? Eventually I want to get the value for each line for example `234`, `12` and `3:44` and store it inside the database.

Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Explanations given below:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    stripped_lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]

words = ["number1", "number2", "time"]
for a_line in stripped_lines:
    for word in words:
        if word in a_line:
            number = a_line.split()[1]
            print(number)
```

1) First of all 'rb' gives bytes object i.e something like `b'number1 234'` would be returned use 'r' to get string object.

2) The lines you read will be something like this and it will be stored in a list.

`['number1 234\r\n', 'number2 12\r\n', '\r\n', 'time 3:44']`

Notice the `\r\n` those specify that you have a newline. To remove use `strip()`.

3) Take each `line` from `stripped_lines` and take each `word` from `words`
and check if that word is present in that line using `in`.

4)`a_line` would be `number1 234` but we only want the number part. So `split()`
output of that would be

`['number1','234']` and `split()[1]` would mean the element at index 1. (2nd element).

5) You can also check if the string is a digit using `your_string.isdigit()`

**UPDATE:** ***Since you updated your question and input file this works:***

```
import time

def isTimeFormat(input):
    try:
        time.strptime(input, '%H:%M')
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    stripped_lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]

words = ["number1", "number2", "time"]
for a_line in stripped_lines:
    for word in words:
        if word in a_line:
            number = a_line.split()[-1] if (a_line.split()[-1].isdigit() or isTimeFormat(a_line.split()[-1]))  else a_line.split()[-2] 
            print(number)
```

why this `isTimeFormat()` function?

```
def isTimeFormat(input):
        try:
            time.strptime(input, '%H:%M')
            return True
        except ValueError:
```

To check if 3:44 or 4:55 is time formats. Since you are considering them as values too.
Final output:

```
234
12
3:44
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I wrote my own answer based on your suggestion. as for the `isTimeFormat`, I prefer to just get the value as a string and keep it in database for example

Answer (score 0):

After some try and error, I found a solution like below. This is based on answer provided by @s_vishnu

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    stripped_lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]

    for item in stripped_lines:
        if "number1" in item:
            getval = item.split("actual ")[1].split(" ")[0]
            print getval

        if "number2" in item:
            getval2 = item.split("number2 ")[1].split(" ")[0]
            print getval2

        if "time" in item:
            getval3 = item.split("number3 ")[1].split(" ")[0]
            print getval3
```

output

```
234
12
3:44
```

This way, I can also do other things for example saving each data to a database.

I am open to any suggestion to further improve my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You're overthinking this. Assuming you don't have those two asterisks at the end of the first line and you want to print out lines containing a certain value(s), you can just read the file line by line, check if any of the chosen values match and print out the last value (value between a space and the end of the line) - no need to parse/split the whole line at all:

```
search_values = ["number1", "number2", "time"]  # values to search for

with open("test.txt", "r") as f:  # open your file
    for line in f:  # read it it line by line
        if any(value in line for value in search_values):  # check for search_values in line
            print(line[line.rfind(" ") + 1:].rstrip())  # print the last value after space
```

Which will give you:

```
234
12
3:44
```

If you do have asterisks you have to more precisely define your file format as splitting won't necessarily yield you your desired value.

Comment: those asterisks are just examples. It can be other multiple letter/number/symbol or it could be no other letter/number/symbol just like line `/// 45daa;: number2 12`. I just want to get the value for `number1` that is `234`. Since you are saying that splitting won't give me the result, do you have any other idea how to get the value?

Comment: @Fang - but what is the meaning of 'value for number1' - data that directly follows it separated by a space on each side?

Comment: yes. I am sorry if my question is not clear to you. It might be easy if `number1:234` instead `number1 234` but just in case if it like that, what should I do to get the `234`?

Comment: The thing is - you need to define what a 'value' is, and what makes it a value compared to the 'search term'. Also, could the search term appear anywhere in the line and what separates the value from the rest if it does. Consider `number1.483 foo` - in this case is the search term `number`, `number1` or `number.1.483`; is the value `1.483` or `.483`, `483` or `foo`? Without precisely defining all the ways your `search term` and `value` pairs can appear in relation to each other we cannot help you figure out how to obtain it.